# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when UIButton is directly add to the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I am new to autolayout. What i am trying to do is adding `UIButton` from the storyboard and setting the contraints from the code. Once i do that its gives me the error

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Because it automatically sets constraints to the `UIButton` when i add the button to the storyboard. But to stop the applying the constraints i am setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

But it still gives me the same error. But if i create button programmatically and if i set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and set constraints programmatically it won't give an error.

I just need to clarify that if we add a `UIButton` to storyboard, the only way to apply constraints to it is from the storyboard or can we apply constraints programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not add specific constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: No, I just want to add like that. Just curious whether its possible or not.

Comment: It is, but you need to ensure that all conflicting constraints are removed first, which is hard because you don't know exactly what they are. Best do it all in storyboard or all in code.

Comment: @wain Thanks alot. I will follow it.